# Why write to an external disk I only looked at?

Tags: external-hdd

I mounted an external disk, looked at its contents in the file browser, and then did "safely remove drive".  Surprise: a small window pops up stating that it's writing to the disk and warning me not to unplug the drive until it's done.   What the heck is there to be written?   I did not create any files, or change any file names, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you look at files or directories - **access-times** are written to the filesystem.

It a pretty big deal if you are doing forensics. In those cases you surly want to **mount as read-only**.

Also if access to the fs was previously cut in the middle of an operation (unmounted improperly) then the next time you mount it - a recovery will make modification to the fs to bring it to a consistent state by consulting the journal.

Comment: Extending this: If you want to change the access time writes, you can change your /etc/fstab to: `noatime`, `relatime`, etc. Check [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#atime_options) for more info.

Comment: Also at mount time the file-system is marked as mounted.

Comment: Also for removable media mounting it in sync mode, will be safer and quicker to dismount.

Comment: @richard: But slower to write to in some/many scenarios.